# Slow running query with full outer join

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Good morning stackoverflow.

I have a query that is running very slow (takes about 25 seconds to return 50 rows).
Basically I have 2 inner queries inside a larger query, the 2 inner queries run quickly separately but when I join them with a full outer join it gets very slow.

Here is my code:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME, @EndDate DATETIME

SET @StartDate = '20131106'
SET @EndDate = '20131107';

WITH al
     AS (SELECT at.Date AS 'Note Date',
                at.ApplicationID,
                at.Comment,
                at.UserID
         FROM   ApplicationTimeline AS at
         WHERE  ( at.[Date] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate + '23:59:59' )
                AND ( at.EventID = 1 ) -- UW notes
                AND ( at.Title = 'Allocation Note' )),
     cm
     AS (SELECT cm.IdentityID,
                cm.ApplicationID,
                cm.ReminderFeedback,
                cm.timestamp,
                (SELECT dbo.udf_StripHTML(cm.Comments)) AS 'Comments'
         FROM   tblCaseManagement AS cm
         WHERE  cm.timestamp BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)
SELECT a.ApplicationID,
       a.LogDate,
       cmu.ShortName,
       cm.ReminderFeedback,
       cm.timestamp
FROM   al
       FULL OUTER JOIN cm
         ON cm.ApplicationID = al.ApplicationID
       INNER JOIN tblApplication AS a
         ON a.ApplicationID = ISNULL(al.ApplicationID, cm.ApplicationID)
       INNER JOIN tblUser AS cmu
         ON cmu.IdentityID = cm.IdentityID
```

[image: Execution plan]

I might end up writing this as a union but I really want to know why this is so slow.
Any help will be greatly appreshiated, thank you for your time.
Bobby

**UPDATE**

I have found that saving the inner queries into two temp tables then applying the full outer join is super fast.

I don't know why this is improving the query speed so much.

Comment: try to remove this part of your code and let us know if that is the issue: (SELECT dbo.udf_StripHTML(cm.Comments)) as 'Comments'

Comment: thank you for your quick response. Removing that select does not improve the speed of the query. Cheers

Comment: Do you have proper indexes on your joined uid's?

Comment: I believe that the indexes are set up correctly

Comment: Try to use the union. A full outter join ill make a full table scan at each end. Not very nice if you are joining up large datasets